# Derivative of the elementary symmetric functions

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-matrices, symmetric-functions

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix such that its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_n$. For $k=1,2,...,n$, define $\sigma_k(A)$ to be 
$$\sigma_k(A)=\sigma_k(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n),$$
where $\sigma_k(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ is the $k$-th elementary symmetric function, i.e.
$$\sigma_k(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)=\sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots< i_k\leq n}\lambda_{i_1}\cdots\lambda_{i_k}.$$
For example, 
$$\sigma_1(A)=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n=tr(A)\mbox{ and }
\sigma_n(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\cdots\lambda_n=\det(A).$$

My question is: Suppose the entries of $A$ depend on $t$ (so its eigenvalues also depend on $t$), I wonder if there is any formula for 
$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\sigma_k(A)$.

Comment: The $\sigma_k$ are (up to sign) the coefficients of the polynomial $\det (\lambda - A)$, so you just need to differentiate this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the comment and sorry that my question may be little be vague. But what I have in my mind is a general formula for $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\sigma_k(A)$ for a general $A$. If I remember correctly, there is some formula related to $T_{k-1}(A)$, the $(k-1)$-th Newton transformation. But I tried to search on the Internet and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Lets $\sigma_{k,i}$ the terms of $\sigma_k$ that dont contains $\lambda_i$, then $\dfrac{\partial \sigma_k}{\partial \lambda _i}=\sigma_{k,i}$. I hope this will help you.